# Changing the position of NSOutlineView disclosure triangle and setting up icons for child nodes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, outline-view

I am creating an OutlineView like this:

[image: My OutlineView]

And I want to achieve a view which looks like this:

[image: Desired view]

The 2 issues that I am facing are:

1. I cant find a way to move the disclosure triangle between the folder icon and the name.
2. I am unable to setup the "P" icon for the child nodes.

For the 2nd issue, this is the code I tried setting up the icon with:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(NSCell*)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn item:(id)item
{
    NSImage* image = nil;
    BOOL isLeaf = [item isLeaf];
    
    if ([[aTableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"styleIcon"]) {
        
        if (aTableView == _charOutlineView) {
             image = [QXPGeneralInterfaces imageFor:(isLeaf ? kCharacterIconImage : kFolderIconImage)];
        }
        else {
            image = [QXPGeneralInterfaces imageFor:(isLeaf ? kParagraphIconImage : kFolderIconImage)];
        }
        
        if (image != nil) {
            [aCell setImage:image];
        }
}
```

aCell does set the image but somehow it disappears in the UI.

Comment: Ask one question per question please. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cant find a way to move the disclosure triangle between the folder icon and the name.

Put the folder icon in column 0 and the title in column 1. Set `outlineTableColumn` (or the Outline Column in IB) to column 1.